# Cursor position is not working in syncfusion richtexteditor ver(18.4.0.30) in xamarin forms for blinking cursor at very first in case of lengthy text

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, syncfusion

In case of lengthy text in editor I want to show cursor blinking so that user should know he/she has to type here. But after focusing editor and setting cursor position it's not working.

Comment: try the latest version 19.2.0.59

Comment: Can you display the code to show us how you set the cursor position and focus editor?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have tried with latest version 19.2.0.59 still not working as expected

Comment: edtAddNotes.Focus();
edtAddNotes.CursorPosition = 15;    This is my code

Comment: this is the correct code [according to the docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/rich-text-editor/basic-features?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#cursor-position) and only iOS should have issues. Raise a support ticket on their support page

Comment: Okay,I will create support ticket ...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The CursorPosition based on the character count will not be working in the Xamarin RichTextEditor iOS due to the control focus limitation. Please find the UG documentation below,
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/rich-text-editor/overview#ios

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks ....Yes,but  in my case it is not working for xamarin forms android